# Convert pytorch geometric data sample to its corresponding line graph

Tags: networkx, torch, linegraph, pytorch-geometric

I'm trying to convert a dataset of torch geometric so that its content is represented as line graphs of the original samples. My code looks likes the following:

```py
G = to_networkx(data,
                node_attrs=['x'],
                edge_attrs=['edge_attr'],
                to_undirected=not directed)
line_graph = nx.line_graph(G, create_using=nx.Graph)
result = from_networkx(line_graph)
```

However, the resulting samples don't have any attribute, neither `edge_attr` nor `x`. At the same time, the label `y` is gone too. Is there a better way to convert it?

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the previous answer, the attributes are not propagated by `line_graph`. Since I'm interested in preserving only the edge attributes, i.e. converting edges to nodes, my solution looks like this:

```py
original_edge_attrs = data.edge_attr
original_edge_names = [(from_.item(), to_.item()) for from_, to_ in zip(data.edge_index[0, :], data.edge_index[1, :])]
original_edge_to_attr = {e: attr for e, attr in zip(original_edge_names, original_edge_attrs)}
G = to_networkx(data,
                node_attrs=['x'],
                edge_attrs=['edge_attr'],
                to_undirected=not directed)
line_graph = nx.line_graph(G, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
res_data = from_networkx(line_graph)

# Copy original attribtues
res_data.x = torch.stack([original_edge_to_attr[e] for e in line_graph.nodes])
res_data.y = data.y
```

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation of `nx.line_graph`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.line.line_graph.html) explicitly states:

> Graph, node, and edge data are not propagated to the new graph.

Hence, you would need to transform the attributes on your own. If I understood it correctly, you need to assign the node attributes of `G` to the respective edges in `line_graph` and the `edge_attribute` of `G` would become the node attributes in `line_graph`.

Comment: Thanks, I actually did expect it to convert the attributes automatically as `DGL` does.

Comment: If I see it correctly `DGL` also only does the "easy" part of that task, i.e., assign the old `edge_attr` as node attributes in the `line_graph` - based on their [code](https://docs.dgl.ai/en/0.4.x/_modules/dgl/transform.html#line_graph)

Comment: True, but that's exactly what I need. I'll add my solution here in case someone searches for it in the future.